# Какой стандартный класс в Делфи позволит хранить и выбирать пары ключ(строка)-значение(строка)-индекс в обе стороны?

Tags: delphi, словари, коллекции, generics

Мне нужно хранить связку Ключ(строка) - Индекс(число) - Значение(строка), для того чтобы была возможность:

- имея Индекс - выбрать Значение (очень часто, желательно прямой доступ)
- имея Индекс - выбрать Ключ (нередко)
- имея Ключ - выбрать Значение (редко)

Все пары ключ-ключ уникальные. Индексы монотонные (от 0 до 10 000 например). Данные приходят неотсортированными. Сортировка не важна.

Текущая реализация - 2 симметричных словаря + список:

```
TKMLibraryKey = string;
TKMLibraryLine = string;

fText: TList<TKMLibraryLine>;
fDictionaryKeyIndex: TDictionary<TKMLibraryKey, Word>;
fDictionaryIndexKey: TDictionary<Word, TKMLibraryKey>;
```

Занимаемая память - `(V, K + I, I + K) * n`

Как это можно сделать проще? Может быть есть какой-то словарь с симметричными парами типа Ключ-Ключ? Чтобы можно было ограничиться двумя коллекциями:

```
fText: TList<TKMLibraryLine>;
TBiDiDictionary<TKMLibraryKey, Word>;
```

Только на основе стандартных классов, без всяких внеших библиотек.

Comment: чем плоха реализация на двух словарях? обертку разве что над этим добром написать, чтобы нужные методы были

Comment: @teran дублирование данных по сути. Неужели нету какого-нибудь симметричного словаря-маппинга? Если поможет - все пары ключ-ключ уникальные.

Comment: хэш функцию сделайте которая ключ будет переводить в отрицательное число, и можно сложить все в один словарь с отрицательными и положительными ключами :D зы: в каждой шутке есть доля шутки :D

Comment: там в дебрях реализации словаря ключи-строки не приводятся в числа то? ибо собственно готовая реализация если что.

Comment: @teran смотря в какие числа .. если int32, то держать потом TList такого размера сомнительное занятие ))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Alekcvp натолкнул на мысль.

Первым делом, конечно, можно слегка оптимизировать до:

```
TKMLibraryKey = string;
TKMLibraryLine = string;

fText: TList<TKMLibraryLine>;
fIndexKey: TList<TKMLibraryKey>;
fDictionaryKeyIndex: TDictionary<TKMLibraryKey, Word>;
```

Далее, по мотивам того что предлагает @Alekcvp (только без дублирования строк):

```
fText: TList<TPair<TKMLibraryKey, TKMLibraryLine>>;
fDictionaryKeyIndex: TDictionary<TKMLibraryKey, Word>;
```

Итого два частых сценария имеют доступ за O(1), а редкий - через словарь.

Занимаемая память - `(V, K, K + I) * n`

Comment: Для строк же работает механизм Copy-on-Write, так что, по-идее, физически строки дублироваться не будут (что в вашем случае, что в случае Alekcvp).

Comment: @zed верно, однако DRY.

Answer (score 0):

Я вижу реализацию этого через своего наследника TDictionary, как-то так:

```
type
  PStringPair = ^TStringPair;
  TStringPair = TPair<string, string>;

  FIndexedDidctionary = class
  private
    FIndexes: TArray<TStringPair>;
    FKeyPairs: TDictionary<string, string>;
    function GetKeyByIndex(Index: Word): string;
    function GetValueByIndex(Index: Word): string;
    function GetValueByKey(const Key: string): string; inline;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure Add(Index: Word; const Key, Value: string);
    procedure Remove(Index: Word);
    property KeyByIndex[Index: Word]: string read GetKeyByIndex;
    property ValueByIndex[Index: Word]: string read GetValueByIndex; default;
    property ValueByKey[const Key: string]: string read GetValueByKey;
  end;


{ FIndexedDidctionary }

procedure FIndexedDidctionary.Add(Index: Word; const Key, Value: string);
const
  INDEX_GROW_CHUNK = 1024;
begin
  if Index >= Length(FIndexes) then
    SetLength(FIndexes, (Index div INDEX_GROW_CHUNK + 1) * INDEX_GROW_CHUNK);

  FKeyPairs.Add(Key, Value);
  FIndexes[Index] := TStringPair.Create(Key, Value);
end;

constructor FIndexedDidctionary.Create;
begin
  FKeyPairs := TDictionary<string, string>.Create;
end;

destructor FIndexedDidctionary.Destroy;
begin
  FKeyPairs.Free;
end;

function FIndexedDidctionary.GetKeyByIndex(Index: Word): string;
begin
  if Index >= Length(FIndexes) then
    Exit(''); // при желании можно заменить на raise Exception
  Result := FIndexes[Index].Key;
end;

function FIndexedDidctionary.GetValueByIndex(Index: Word): string;
begin
  if Index >= Length(FIndexes) then
    Exit(''); // при желании можно заменить на raise Exception
  Result := FIndexes[Index].Value;
end;

function FIndexedDidctionary.GetValueByKey(const Key: string): string;
begin
  Result := FKeyPairs[Key];
end;

procedure FIndexedDidctionary.Remove(Index: Word);
begin
  if Index >= Length(FIndexes) then
    Exit; // при желании можно заменить на raise Exception
  var Item := PStringPair(@FIndexes[Index]);
  FKeyPairs.Remove(Item.Key);
  Item.Key := '';
  Item.Value := '';
end;
```

Код выше - это пример из блокнота, на работоспособность не проверял. Подразумевается только добавление и удаление элементов по индексу, но не изменение существующих.